# Why did Amenadiel almost die?

Tags: character, lucifer

In Lucifer's final episode of the first season we saw that Amenadiel almost died because of Maze's knife. But for Lucifer it was nothing. In previous episodes Maze threw knives at him.

Assuming that and that they are brothers: Why did the knife almost kill one and did nothing to another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you missed the key dialogue in the previous episode. When Maze threw the knife at Lucifer and he caught it, he said something like:

> Demon knives forged in Hell don't count, we all know these draw blood.

In other words, those knives *would* have hurt Lucifer, if they have hit him. Maze just assumed Lucifer would catch them, because she'd been throwing harmless "normal" knives at him for a while.

If Lucifer hadn't caught Maze's knife and it had hit him somewhere important, it absolutely would have hurt him, possibly badly. And Amenadiel wasn't just stabbed with a knife: it was driven deep into him, then scraped around inside his gut to ensure that it was a mortal wound.

Answer (score -3):

Lucifer did not get hit by that knife,..thats why he caught it,..its demon forged so it can hurt angels,..the other ones were just knifes

Comment: What value does it add to already existing answer ?